# Fatal error unexpected nil core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, core-data

When, I try read string and write into cell, from core data I get the following **error**:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

save

```
func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    return (appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext)!
}

func save(value:String, forKey:String) {
    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Ostatnie", in: context)

    let adj = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    add.setValue(value, forKey: forKey)

    do {
        try context.save()
        print("save - \(value)")
    } catch {
        print("err zapisu \(error)")
    }
}
```

save

```
save(value: annotation.title!, forKey: "nazwa")
```

get value (have global var nameTab:[String] = [])

```
func get(value:String ) -> String {
    var value2 = value
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Ostatnie> = Ostatnie.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let result = try getContext().fetch(request)

        for liczby in result {
            print(liczby.value(forKey: "nazwa") ?? String.self)
            value2 = liczby.value(forKey: "nazwa") as! String
            nazwaTab.append(wartosc2)
            print(nameTab)

            print(nameTab)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return value2
}
```

and tableView

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nazwaTab.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! cellTableViewCell

    cell.nazwaLabel.text = nameTab[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: cell.nazwaLabel.text = nameTab[indexPath.row] as! String

Comment: can you explain more. On exactly which line your code crashing

Comment: @Lalit Kuma value2 = liczby.value(forKey: "nazwa") as! String on this I get "exc_bad_instruction"

Comment: @SarabjitSingh not working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code. Your code crashing is because either it is getting nil value from liczby["nazwa"] or value which is of other type than String.

```
if let str = liczby["nazwa"] as? String {
   value2 = str
}
```

Comment: Em, I have another question, how can I display it now on tableView? code like on topic

Comment: Show some "default value" or don't append `nazwaTab`. So, you will contain only cell for which value is available

Comment: [link](http://www.wklej.org/id/3043881/) that's my tabvView, on cellTableViewCell I have only outlets